# Suppose that A is an n × n matrix with eigenvalues, show that: $y(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_iv_ie^{{\lambda_i}t}$ is a solution to the ODE $y'=Ay$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Let n ∈ N denote a (fixed) dimension. Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with eigenvalues
$λ_1,\dots, λ_n$ and corresponding eigenvectors $v_1,\dots, v_n$. Additionally, suppose that $v_1,\dots, v_n$ are
distinct (linearly independent). Where $α_1,\dots, α_n$ are arbitrary constants, show that: $$y(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i e^{{\lambda_i}t}$$ is a solution to the ODE $$y'=Ay$$

I feel like this is not a very difficult question and thus this is what I have done so far:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=Ay$$
$$\int\frac{1}{Ay}dy=\int{dt}$$
$$\ln y=At$$
$$y=\exp(At)$$

and thus A represents the summation part of the given solution.

Am I going in the right direction??

Comment: It is not difficult you're correct. But you did not prove it. You need to plug in the Ansatz (your linear combination of eigenvectors) and show that it satisfies the ODE written. What you did was suppose $A$ was a number, but it is a matrix and so $1/Ay$ has no meaning.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?